# Why is my piezo so innacurate? Is it just insensitive?

Tags: voltage, piezo, sensitivity

I'm trying to make a sound level display, simply to tell the user how loud nearby sounds are. The issue is this data, which I collected in a near silent environment (it's night, and I can't make out any distinct sounds):

> 521
>   ... 214
>   ... 614
>   ... 79
>   ... 698
>   ... 11
>   ... 636
>   ... 136
>   ... 544
>   ... 291
>   ... 424
>   ... 440
>   ... 301
>   ... 547
>   ... 179
>   ... 636
>   ... 47
>   ... 691
>   ... 21
>   ... 616
>   ... 173
>   ... 511
>   ... 336
>   ... 395
>   ... 474
>   ... 270
>   ... 571
>   ... 144
>   ... 656
>   ... 25
>   ... 683
>   ... 35
>   ... 580
>   ... 227
>   ... 459
>   ... 373
>   ... 358
>   ... 475
>   ... 261
>   ... 541
>   ... 165
>   ... 600
>   ... 83
>   ... 601
>   ... 103
>   ... 640
>   ... 138
>   ... 545
>   ... 291
>   ... 425
>   ... 439
>   ... 304
>   ... 545

The values range from 11 to 698, which is a pretty large difference (in my admittedly limited experience) and has a load of different values inbetween.

The issue is that creating a sound near it like a finger snap or tapping on it barely affects it. The most I could get it to with what I'd presume to be fairly loud sounds to a piezo (finger clicks, that kind of thing) was 745. You'd assume from the ambient sound range from 11--698 and the loud sound bringing it over to 745, that I was barely making a sound.

Bringing it back to the original question: Why is my piezo so innacurate? Is it just insensitive?

I suspect it may be related to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117970/why-is-my-analog-temp-sensors-signal-so-unstable) but I can't be sure if all piezos are like this, or just when they're powered by USB.

**EDIT:**

Running on an Arduino Uno R3, connected to a laptop using a USB cable through a 2.0 port. The piezo sensor is the PKM22EPP-40 (I believe [this](https://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/PIEZO-PKM22EPPH4001-BO.pdf) is relevant.) It's the one in the official Arduino starter kit.

Using 5V output* from the Arduino. There's also a 16x2 LCD and a potentiometer running on the same line.

---

*This could be completely the wrong term.

**EDIT:**

The piezo: [Piezo capsule [PKM17EPP-4001-B0]](https://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/PIEZO-PKM22EPPH4001-BO.pdf)

Comment: We need to know much more about the system you have, how you are interfacing it, what the pizza sensor is etc.

Comment: Sure, I'll look some of the stuff up and edit. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Edited, although I'm not sure if it helped at all. Mention if there's anything you'd like to know.

Comment: Where's the schematic?

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I didn't realise that a schematic would be needed for a question this general. I'm not necessarily asking about how to fix it, but about the nature of piezos in general. I've never made a schematic though, so that should be a fun thing to do when I can in the morning!

Comment: Well you just dumped data, and a catalog of piezo parts on us. There really isn't much to talk about here. Your data makes me think you're hooking the piezo straight to the analog pin and expecting something to happen, but there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Should I explain why I put what I did? I feel like I should. The data was to show what was happening, and what I meant. I felt like I should put that in there to avoid any confusion. The catalogue parts were asked for, I didn't mean to dump them on you guys. The last thing: I'm not sure what you mean by "expecting something to happen" in that yes, if I wire a circuit, and program a chip to take input in, I do expect something to happen. I expect data to be taken in. I'm just asking if this kind of fluctuation is normal in a piezo, and I gave some numbers to show what I meant.

Comment: @HarryCBurn I found this which is similar to what you are doing which may help you. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KnockSensor

Comment: @Matt I understand that it can be frustrating helping people new to a topic (I've answered a fair amount of questions for newbies on other sites), I'd hate for you to be annoyed at my inexperience c:

Comment: @Digital Thanks! They covered something with the exact same concept in a book I was reading, and it never seemed to work all that well then either. Perhaps I'm making the same mistake twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a schematic, and without knowing your ADC sample rate, I would guess that you have hooked your PZT (I like pizza sensor, though) directly from ground to the R3 input. In this case, I'd very strongly suspect 60 Hz pickup. PZTs are very high-resistance, and their capacitance is not so enormous that I'd count on it acting as a filter, especially when hooked up as I think.

If your sample rate is low (low kHz) it's entirely possible that you're simply missing your impulse noises most of the time.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what 60Hz pickup is briefly? I couldn't find anything on it after a Google search. I'll try increasing the amount of times I take in data, and see if that helps.

Comment: The electrical system in your house runs on 60 Hz AC. Any current which flows in your wires causes them to act like a radio transmitter (but at 60 Hz). Any wire within range acts like a receiver. The effect is small, but you have a potentially sensitive circuit. See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum For your test, try to include a peak detector.

Comment: The data's fluctuating in [waves](http://pastebin.com/22Z6ZLDy), so yeah, I think it is 60Hz pickup!

Comment: And a simple look at the data says your only sampling at about a 400 Hz rate (~7 samples per cycle) but that may be an aliasing artifact (you can look up "aliasing"). If so, it explains why you usually miss your test noises - they are so brief that you have to be lucky to catch them,

Comment: See if you can increase the sample rate even more.